# What do the chained namespace identifiers in Perl do?

Tags: perl, oop

I found a code snippet which goes like this:

```
package File::MP3;
use parent 'File';    # sets @File::MP3::ISA = ('File');
my $mp3 = File::MP3->new( 'Andvari.mp3', $data );
$mp3->save();
```

Here, I want to ask if `File::MP3` is just a name (it is named that way *just* to show that it inherits from `File`)

**OR**

We have to name it that way if it inherits from `File`?

Comment: Calling `File::MP3->new()` *within* the package/class `File::MP3` seems strange. First, explict reference to the current namespace (`File::MP3`) is not required when calling the `new` method of the current class *within* the same class. Maybe I am missing something? Did you mean `use File::MP3` instead of `package File::MP3`?

Comment: No, I meant what it says. The link for the snippet is the Perl documentation [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) under the Inheritance heading.

Comment: I think that the last two lines 3-4 in that example belong in a different file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

> I made a module named `Module.pm` in `lib` folder, & then named the package as `package lib::Module`

You're getting a little confused

When `use` or `require` is actioned, Perl will form a *relative path* from the package name by changing something like `My::Other::Module` to `My/Other/Module.pm` using the obvious substitutions

It will look for that relative path in the list of locations in the built-in `@INC` array, which contains some paths that were defined when perl was built and others that may be added at run time

Up until very recently, `@INC` contained the current working directory, `.`, so if you have your module in `./lib/My/Other/Module.pm` then the Perl compiler will find it if you `use lib::My::Other::Module.pm`. But that's not how it's meant to work

You should add `./lib` to `@INC` (using either `use lib './lib'`<sup>[1]</sup> or by adding to the value of the environment variable `PERL5LIB`) and then `use My::Other::Module`. That will work fine because perl is looking for the .pm file in in `./lib`. The name and path to the .pm file, the `package` statement, and the `use` statement should all agree about what the name is

**[1]** *Note that it is a security risk to add relative paths to `@INC`. That is why `.` is no longer included as standard in the release client for Perl v5.26. That means you shouldn't `use lib './lib'` as described above. Instead you need something like `use lib '/var/users/Me/Perl/source/lib'`*

---

A package name like `File::MP3` is just a name. Perl's only requirement is that it has to be unique

But modules are grouped into *families* in CPAN, and most *file-related* modules begin with `File::`. There is also `Win32::`, `Net::`, `Math::` etc.

It is also used to indicate subsidiary modules in a suite. For instance, `Mojo::Message` contains the code common to both `Mojo::Message::Request` and `Mojo::Message::Response`. But that is a mnemonic for the programmer's convenience only

In the case of `Math::Poisson`, perl will look for a file `Math/Poisson.pm` which should have a `package` declaration `package Math::Poisson`. If you use that package name elsewhere then anything you declare will be inserted into the module's namespace

Comment: You mean having the package name declaration `package Math::Poisson` or `package Poisson` will have the same effect in the file Poisson.pm, given that it is in the Math folder? Is it just acc. to my convenience?

Comment: @BillGates no. The package name is exactly what you write down. Perl expects a file that provides the package `Foo::Bar` to be in the file `Foo/Bar.pm`. If you say `use Foo::Bar` Perl will look in every folder that is included in `@INC` for a folder `Foo` with a file `Bar.pm`, then `require` that file, and then call `Foo::Bar->import`.

Comment: It is confusing because I made a module named `Module.pm` in `lib` folder, & then named the package as `package lib::Module`, still Perl finds the module using `use lib::Module`. I now have to use it in code by `$lib::Module::variable` instead of `$Module::variable`. But why did Perl find a package named `lib::Module` inside the `lib` folder when the expected statement should be `use lib::lib::Module`?

Comment: @BillGates  If the module file is called `Module.pm` and it is in a folder `lib` then its package should indeed be named `package lib::Module` and it should indeed be used as `use lib::Module;`.  This is how it works, the `use` uses `require` which parses `lib::Module` so to look for a file `Module.pm` in a folder `lib` (see my answer).

Comment: @Borodin Thanks. At last, you got exactly where I was struggling at past 2 hours. Accepted.

Comment: @zdim: I think that's very misleading. Ordinarily `./lib` will be in `@INC` while the package is called `Module`.

Comment: @Borodin I think they meant a `lib` somewhere else, since they say that `use lib::Module;` works (not `use Module;`).  Either way, it's been cleared up.

Answer (score 2):

The `File::MP3` in the [package](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) declaration is just a name.  However, if you want to [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) that package then the name matters.  The `use` dispatches to [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), for which the name in `require EXPR` is

> If EXPR is a bareword, require assumes a *.pm* extension and replaces `::` with `/` in the filename for you, to make it easy to load standard modules. This form of loading of modules does not risk altering your namespace.

Thus if you want to `use File::MP3` then an *`MP3.pm`* file had better be in a *`File/`* directory, which needs to be in one of (the absolute-path) directories listed in `@INC`.

The class `File` from which `File::MP3` inherits has nothing to do with the directory *`File/`*. The `use parent` (see [parent](https://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html)) independently specifies the package to load for the class `File`, and its *`File.pm`* file also has to be found in `@INC`.

The *`MP3.pm`* file with the package may well be in a *`Media/`* directory, in which case it would be best named as `package Media::MP3;` and would be loaded with `use Media::MP3;` – and it can still inherit from the `File` class by `use parent File;`

Placing file-related modules in a directory named *`File`* does make sense, of course.

Comment: Actually, `File/MP3.pm` need not exist if a coderef in `@INC` takes care of `require`ing the file.

Comment: @SinanÜnür I held back from mentioning exceptions and workarounds, thinking that this is more of a basic question. (Didn't know that it can be a coderef in `@INC` -- thank you!)

Comment: @SinanÜnür  Thanks for the full example of what you mentioned! (Even as you then removed it. I hope you don't mind that I peeked :)  It's quite interesting.

Comment: Of course, not. The OP's question really was different than what the title said. One can do fun things with coderefs in `@INC`. Reminds me of the time I deduced a dependency tree for a codebase that could not be run because none of the dependencies were there. See also, for example, [Require::Hook::MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Require::Hook::MetaCPAN). `perldoc -f require`: "*You can also insert hooks into the import facility by putting Perl code directly into the @INC array. There are three forms of hooks: subroutine references, array references, and blessed objects.*"

Comment: @SinanÜnür  Thank you. That module seems extremely interesting and a great example.  Thanks for the `require` tip, I never noticed that part.  I respect Perl's docs and try to be aware of what's in them ... but there is a lot.  Need to keep re-reading all the time.